# Opencv vid.read() sometimes returning False

Tags: python, opencv

I suddenly started having this weird error when I read video using OpenCV on EC2 after switching from gp2 to gp3 EBS. My program essentially downloads video from S3 and starts reading in Python. This used to work for a few years but recently after switching from gp2 to gp3 I started getting this weird error, but not always. Usually, after reboot it works. This is making it really hard to troubleshoot.

The only thing that changed was switching from gp2 to gp3. Could this possibly have an effect on how video is read by OpenCV? Or anything else? The video is functional and the path is correct as it works after reboot.

OpenCV can see all the information about the video:

For example:

```
print(f"Codex: {int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))}. FPS: {vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)}. Video Size: {(int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))}")

print(f"Video Frame Count: {vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)}. Vid Length: {int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))}. Width: {int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))}. Height: {int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))}")
```

Returns this:

```
Codex: 828601953. FPS: 25.0. Video Size: (1920, 1080)
Video Frame Count: 161100.0. Vid Length: 161100. Width: 1920. Height: 1080
```

Thanks.